# Salbutamol's Pathways of Interaction and Classification

Tags: pharmacology, autonomic-nervous-system

Salbutamol is a very commonly used direct-acting β2-agonist. 
This suggests me that it is sympatholytic. 
However, it has sympathomimetic pathways, see [PubChem](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/salbutamol#section=Biological-Test-Results) for Sympathomimetic.

I am trying to think the group of Salbutamol. 
Sympathomimetic or sympatholytic.

**How can you classify Salbutamol into a group?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *agonist* works with the receptor: a substance that initiates a physiological response when combined with a receptor; in the case of salbutamol (or albutarol in the US) they activate the beta-2 receptor on the muscles surrounding the airways. They are also known as sympathomimetics, as they imitate β2 adrenergics.

A *blocker* (or antagonist) is one that that blocks the action of endogenous catecholamines; for that reason, they are also called sympatholytic: antagonistic to or inhibiting the transmission of nerve impulses in the sympathetic nervous system.

It appears you have experienced a simple confusion in terms. Salbutamol/albuterol is definitely a sympathomimetic, used extensively on asthma and COPD.

[Pharmacology and Therapeutics of Bronchodilators](http://pharmrev.aspetjournals.org/content/64/3/450.full)

Comment: You seem to be right. I read this **A short-acting beta-2 adrenergic agonist** as **beta-adrenergic antagonist** which is false. Thank you for excellent answer!